# How do I select the value with SERIAL data type in postgres

Tags: postgresql, select

I want to know how to select values from a column that has SERIAL data type.

I already try to do that but the output is like this 'Resource id #3', and not just '3'

I use SERIAL so I dont have to input ID like when I use integer

Answer (score 2):

There is no *actual* [`serial` data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL). `serial` is just a notational convenience.
The resulting data type is `integer` for `serial` or `bigint` for `bigserial`

Related answer on SO with more details:
[Auto increment SQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-sql-function/9875517#9875517)

You'd have to be more specific for a more specific answer.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47098/how-do-i-determine-if-a-column-is-defined-as-a-serial-data-type-instead-of-an-in (self plug!)