# Constraint to enforce "at least one" or "exactly one" in a database

Tags: postgresql, database-design, constraint, ddl, referential-integrity

Say we have users and each user can have multiple email addresses

```
CREATE TABLE emails (
    user_id integer,
    email_address text,
    is_active boolean
)
```

Some sample rows

```
user_id | email_address | is_active
1       | alice@bar.com   | t
1       | alice@foo.com   | f
1       | alice@web.com   | f
2       | bob@ddd.com     | t
```

I want to enforce a constraint that every user has exactly one active address. How can I do this in Postgres? I could do this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "user_email" ON emails(user_id) WHERE is_active=true;
```

Which would protect against a user having more than one active address, but wouldn't, I believe, protect against all of their addresses being set to false.

If possible I'd prefer to avoid a trigger or a pl/pgsql script, as we don't currently have any of those & it would be difficult to set up. But I would appreciate knowing "the only way to do this is with a trigger or pl/pgsql", if that is the case.

Answer (score 25):

You don't need triggers or PL/pgSQL at all.
You don't even *need* `DEFERRABLE` constraints.
And you don't need to store any information redundantly.

Include the ID of the active email in the `users` table, resulting in mutual references. One might think we need a `DEFERRABLE` constraint to solve the chicken-and-egg problem of inserting a user and his active email, but using data-modifying CTEs we don't even need that.

This enforces ***exactly one active email per user*** at all times:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id  serial PRIMARY KEY
, username text NOT NULL
, email_id int NOT NULL  -- FK to active email, constraint added below
);

CREATE TABLE email (
  email_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, user_id  int NOT NULL REFERENCES users ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE 
, email    text NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT email_fk_uni UNIQUE(user_id, email_id)  -- for FK constraint below
);
    
ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT active_email_fkey
FOREIGN KEY (user_id, email_id) REFERENCES email(user_id, email_id);
```

Remove the `NOT NULL` constraint from `users.email_id` to make it "at most one active email". (You can still store multiple emails per user, but none of them is "active".)

Aside: If `(user_id, email)` is unique (as can be assumed), you might use `email` directly instead of `email_id` ...

You *can* make `active_email_fkey` `DEFERRABLE` to allow more leeway (insert user and email in separate commands of the *same* transaction), but that's ***not necessary***.

I put `user_id` first in the `UNIQUE` constraint `email_fk_uni` to optimize index coverage. Details:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

Optional view:

```
CREATE VIEW user_with_active_email AS
SELECT * FROM users JOIN email USING (user_id, email_id);
```

Here's how you insert new users with an active email (as required):

```
WITH new_data(username, email) AS (
   VALUES
      ('usr1', 'abc@d.com')   -- new users with *1* active email
    , ('usr2', 'def3@d.com')
    , ('usr3', 'ghi1@d.com')
   )
, u AS (
   INSERT INTO users(username, email_id)
   SELECT n.username, nextval('email_email_id_seq'::regclass)
   FROM   new_data n
   RETURNING *
   )
INSERT INTO email(email_id, user_id, email)
SELECT u.email_id, u.user_id, n.email
FROM   u
JOIN   new_data n USING (username);
```

The specific difficulty is that we have neither `user_id` nor `email_id` to begin with. Both are serial numbers provided from the respective `SEQUENCE`. It can't be solved with a single `RETURNING` clause (another chicken-and-egg problem). The solution is `nextval()` as [explained in detail in the linked answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24816197/939860).

If you don't *know* the name of the attached sequence for the `serial` column `email.email_id` you can replace:

```
nextval('email_email_id_seq'::regclass)
```

with

```
nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('email', 'email_id'))
```

Here's how you add a new "active" email:

```
WITH e AS (
   INSERT INTO email (user_id, email)
   VALUES  (3, 'new_active@d.com')
   RETURNING *
   )
UPDATE users u
SET    email_id = e.email_id
FROM   e
WHERE  u.user_id = e.user_id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2fb504c975ccee1d9323ce1e1aec8da4)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fb1b0/1)</sub>

You might encapsulate the SQL commands in server-side functions if some simple-minded ORM isn't smart enough to cope with this.

Closely related, with ample explanation:

- [How to deal with mutually recursive inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24816197/939860)
- [Complex foreign key constraint in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8395021/939860)

Also related:

- [Enforcing constraints "two tables away"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58970/enforcing-constraints-two-tables-away/58972#58972)

About `DEFERRABLE` constraints:

- [Constraint defined DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE is still DEFERRED?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10032272/939860)

About `nextval()` and `pg_get_serial_sequence()`:

- [PostgreSQL SELECT primary key as "serial" or "bigserial"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90555/postgresql-select-primary-key-as-serial-or-bigserial/90567#90567)
- [Duplicate row with Primary Key in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122120/duplicate-row-with-primary-key-in-postgresql/122144#122144)

Comment: Can this be applied to 1 to at-least-one relationships? Not 1 -1 as shown in this answer.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: Yes. Exactly one *active* email per user is enforced. Nothing keeps you from adding more (non-active) emails for the same user. If you don't want the special role for the active email, triggers would be a (less strict) alternative. But you have to be careful to cover all updates and deletes. I suggest you ask a *question* if you need this.

Comment: Is there any way to delete users without using `ON DELETE CASCADE`?  Just curious (cascading is working fine for now).

Comment: @amoe: There are various ways. Data-modifying CTEs, triggers, rules, multiple statements in the same transaction, ... it all depends on exact requirements. Ask a new question with your specifics if you need an answer. You can always link to this one for context.

Comment: i am guessing this works if your data type is a serial but what if your columns are generated always as identity

Comment: @PirateApp: Not sure I understand the question. Please post an actual *question* with sufficient context. You can always link to this one for context and drop a comment here to link back (and get my attention).

Answer (score 6):

If you can add a column to the table, the following scheme would *almost*<sup>1</sup> work:

```
CREATE TABLE emails 
(
    UserID integer NOT NULL,
    EmailAddress varchar(254) NOT NULL,
    IsActive boolean NOT NULL,

    -- New column
    ActiveAddress varchar(254) NOT NULL,

    -- Obvious PK
    CONSTRAINT PK_emails_UserID_EmailAddress
        PRIMARY KEY (UserID, EmailAddress),

    -- Validate that the active address row exists
    CONSTRAINT FK_emails_ActiveAddressExists
        FOREIGN KEY (UserID, ActiveAddress)
        REFERENCES emails (UserID, EmailAddress),

    -- Validate the IsActive value makes sense    
    CONSTRAINT CK_emails_Validate_IsActive
    CHECK 
    (
        (IsActive = true AND EmailAddress = ActiveAddress)
        OR
        (IsActive = false AND EmailAddress <> ActiveAddress)
    )
);

-- Enforce maximum of one active address per user
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_emails_One_IsActive_True_PerUser
ON emails (UserID, IsActive)
WHERE IsActive = true;
```

**<kbd>[Test SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5ef3c/4)</kbd>**

*<sub>Translated from my native SQL Server, with help from [a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name)</sub>*

As [ypercube](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube) mentioned in a comment, you could even go further:

- Drop the boolean column; and
- Create the `UNIQUE INDEX ON emails (UserID) WHERE (EmailAddress = ActiveAddress)`

The effect is the same, but it is arguably simpler and neater.

---

<sup>1</sup> The problem is that the existing constraints only ensure that a row referred to as 'active' by another row *exists*, not that it is also actually active. I don't know Postgres well enough to implement the extra constraint myself (at least not right now), but in SQL Server, it could be done thusly:

```
CREATE TABLE Emails 
(
    EmailID integer NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    UserID integer NOT NULL,
    EmailAddress varchar(254) NOT NULL,
    IsActive bit NOT NULL,

    -- New columns
    ActiveEmailID integer NOT NULL,
    ActiveIsActive AS CONVERT(bit, 'true') PERSISTED,

    -- Obvious PK
    CONSTRAINT PK_emails_UserID_EmailAddress
        PRIMARY KEY (UserID, EmailID),

    CONSTRAINT UQ_emails_UserID_EmailAddress_IsActive
        UNIQUE (UserID, EmailID, IsActive),

    -- Validate that the active address exists and is active
    CONSTRAINT FK_emails_ActiveAddressExists_And_IsActive
        FOREIGN KEY (UserID, ActiveEmailID, ActiveIsActive)
        REFERENCES emails (UserID, EmailID, IsActive),

    -- Validate the IsActive value makes sense    
    CONSTRAINT CK_emails_Validate_IsActive
    CHECK 
    (
        (IsActive = 'true' AND EmailID = ActiveEmailID)
        OR
        (IsActive = 'false' AND EmailID <> ActiveEmailID)
    )
);

-- Enforce maximum of one active address per user
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_emails_One_IsActive_PerUser
ON emails (UserID, IsActive)
WHERE IsActive = 'true';
```

This effort improves a little on the original by using a surrogate rather than duplicating the full email address.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to do either of these without schema changes is with a PL/PgSQL trigger.

For the "exactly one" case, you can make the references mutual, with one being `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`. So `A.b_id` (FK) references `B.b_id` (PK) and `B.a_id` (FK) references `A.a_id` (PK). Many ORMs etc cannot cope with deferrable constraints though. So in this case you'd add a deferrable FK from user to address on a column `active_address_id`, *instead* of using an `active` flag on `address`.

Comment: The FK doesn't even have to be `DEFERRABLE`.