# Make a boolean column unique per group

Tags: postgresql, database-design, referential-integrity, unique-constraint

I want to ensure consistency and make sure only one phone line is the default for a house.

```
Schema: PhoneLine
ID | isDefault | HouseID
```

I want to add a trigger so that when you add/update a row, and set `isDefault` to `True`, all other rows in same table with the same `HouseID` set `isDefault` to `False`.

I can't figure out a way to do this without creating a recursive mess.

What's the best way of approaching it?

I tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unsetCurrentDefault() 
RETURNS trigger AS $unsetCurrentDefault$
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.isdefault AND NEW.houseid IS NOT NULL THEN
            -- Current ones get reset.
            UPDATE phoneline SET isdefault = false 
            WHERE houseid = NEW.houseid AND id <> NEW.id AND isdefault;
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$unsetCurrentDefault$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER updateDefaultValue AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON PhoneLine
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE unsetCurrentDefault();
```

But the behaviour seems recursive.

Comment: You don't need a trigger to enforce this (off course you may use it, if you want put the updating logic in a trigger). A unique filtered index will enforce your constraint: `UNIQUE (houseID) WHERE (isDefault)`

Comment: Looks like you intend to reset rows with the same `HouseID` (not with the same `ID`). And it's confusing that the trigger is on a mysterious `patienttable` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The superior implementation is to save the default choice with the row in the parent table. Then a new default *replaces* the old one automatically. No trigger required, no chance to break referential integrity

Data model based on fragments in the question:

```
CREATE TABLE house (
   house_id         serial PRIMARY KEY
 , default_phone_id int
 -- , other columns
);

CREATE TABLE phoneline (
   phone_id serial PRIMARY KEY
 , house_id int  NOT NULL REFERENCES house 
 , number   text NOT NULL
 , UNIQUE (house_id, phone_id)  -- seems redundant, but needed for FK below
);

ALTER TABLE house ADD CONSTRAINT house_default_phone_id_fkey
FOREIGN KEY (house_id, default_phone_id) REFERENCES phoneline(house_id, phone_id);
```

The circular FK references may seem like a problem. But, really, they are not.

I made the FK constraint `house_default_phone_id_fkey` include `house_id`, so that setting the default to a phone number of a different house is impossible. The FK requires a `UNIQUE (house_id, phone_id)` in `phoneline`, which seems a bit redundant since `phone_id` is the PK. But you typically need an index with `house_id` as leading column for performance anyway.

Since the `default_phone_id` can be NULL, you can choose the default later, *after* inserting one or more phone numbers. But it even works with the column set to `NOT NULL`; just use data-modifying CTEs to insert & update in a single statement. Reference implementation:

- [How to deal with mutually recursive inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813000/how-to-deal-with-mutually-recursive-inserts/24816197#24816197)

Related:

- [Constraint to enforce "at least one" or "exactly one" in a database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112061/constraint-to-enforce-at-least-one-or-exactly-one-in-a-database/112144#112144)
- [Enforcing constraints "two tables away"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58970/enforcing-constraints-two-tables-away/58972#58972)