# Postgres how to update first row in the child table for all parent entries

Tags: postgresql, update

I have a table parent table **workflow** and child table **workflow_task** having one to many mapping.

> workflow`

| workID | workTitle |
| --- | --- |
| 1800 | vpInv1231 |
| 1801 | vpInv1231 |

`workflow_task`

| id | task_Type | workflow_id(fk) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 1800 |
| 2 | null | 1800 |

Is there any way I can update all the first row in the child table with `taskType` as 'POC' and rest(from second to so on) as 'Appr'?.

Comment: *update all the first row* How to define what row is "first"?

Comment: task_type is the identifier but it was added now, for now only id's with min value are the identifier

Answer (score 2):

Possible question interpretation:

```sql
UPDATE workflow_task
SET task_Type = CASE WHEN workflow_task.id = first_row.id
                     THEN 'POC'
                     ELSE 'Appr'
                     END
FROM ( SELECT MIN(id) id, workflow_id
       FROM workflow_task
       GROUP BY workflow_id ) first_row
WHERE workflow_task.workflow_id = first_row.workflow_id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=08c60035f735ae557100dde8a7623008

`workflow` table not needed for this operation.

Comment: Thanks a lot Akina

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted @Akina's answer because it was a very simple and elegant way of solving the particular problem posed by the OP.

I looked at the question again and noticed that there are (at least) five other ways of obtaining the same result - using [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-window.html). Window functions (short PostgreSQL tutorial [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/tutorial-window.html)) are an **extremely** powerful tool for querying databases and will repay any effort spent learning them 10 times over.

### EDIT:

There are 6 ways of doing this using window functions - i.e. the [LAG()](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-lag-function/) function - see the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=eede09cf724d0eb754374f4c7b169200). As with ROW_NUMBER() &c. there are two ways of doing this - either "directly" or using the `wf.id DESC` in the `ORDER BY` part of the  OVER() clause of the window function - see discussion below.

### Analysis:

Before starting, it is worth mentioning that **none** of the methods (mine or @Akina's) will work without having either a `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE` (and `NOT NULL`) constraint on both the (id, workflow_id) fields in the `workflow_task` table - otherwise there is no way of distinguishing between different records in the table.

So, my table definition is now (see the fiddle for all code below (and more) [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f494d5ef1fb7ae67c0435525655a7c50)):

```
CREATE TABLE workflow_task 
(
  id INT NOT NULL, 
  task_Type VARCHAR(255), 
  workflow_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT wft_pk PRIMARY KEY (workflow_id, id)
);
```

For testing purposes, I also added more records as follows:

```
INSERT INTO workflow_task VALUES

(1, null,   1800),
(2, null,   1800),
(3, null,   1800),
(4, null,   1800),
(5, null,   1800),
(6, null,   1800),

(7, null,   1900), -- <<=== Note duplication of 7 as id here and below
(8, null,   1900), -- <<=== to make things tricky!
(9, null,   1900),
(10,    null,   1900),
(11,    null,   1900),
(12,    null,   1900),


(7, null,   2000),
(8, null,   2000),
(9, null,   2000),
(10,    null,   2000),
(11,    null,   2000),
(12,    null,   2000);
```

The value(s) of the `id` fields don't matter - they only have to be `UNIQUE` (and `NOT NULL`) in conjunction with the `workflow_id` field - as ensured by the `PRIMARY KEY` in my table definition.

The inital window function method is using the [FIRST_VALUE()](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-first_value-function/) function as follows:

```
UPDATE workflow_task
SET task_type = 
  CASE
    WHEN workflow_task.id = fr.f_id THEN 'XXX'
    ELSE 'YYY'
  END
FROM
(
  SELECT FIRST_VALUE(wf.id) OVER (PARTITION BY wf.workflow_id 
                                  ORDER BY id, workflow_id) AS f_id,
  wf.workflow_id
  FROM workflow_task wf
) AS fr
WHERE workflow_task.workflow_id = fr.workflow_id;
```

Result:

```
id  task_type   workflow_id
1   XXX 1800
2   YYY 1800
3   YYY 1800
4   YYY 1800
5   YYY 1800
6   YYY 1800
7   XXX 1900
8   YYY 1900
...
... snipped for brevity 
...
```

The result is correct and matches @Akina's `MIN(id)` approach - apart from the differing values inserted for testing/visibility purposes.

The second approach makes use of the [ROW_NUMBER()](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/) function.

Now, you may ask, why bother with this (these) approaches when you have a perfectly working solution - the answer lies in the power of window functions. This (relatively simple) question has a relatively simple answer - but **if**, down the road, a requirement arises for more sophisticated criteria to be taken into account - the window functions' approach will become the tool of choice.

For example, with the ROW_NUMBER() approach, you can choose the second id, or the third and so on...

SQL:

```
UPDATE workflow_task
SET task_type = 
  CASE
    WHEN workflow_task.id = fr.id THEN 'AAA'
    ELSE 'BBB'
  END
FROM
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY wf.workflow_id
                                  ORDER BY wf.id, wf.workflow_id) AS f_rn,
  wf.id,
  wf.workflow_id
  FROM workflow_task wf
) AS fr
WHERE workflow_task.workflow_id = fr.workflow_id
AND fr.f_rn = 1;
```

Result:

```
id  task_type   workflow_id
1   AAA 1800
2   BBB 1800
3   BBB 1800
...
... snipped for brevity
...
```

Again, this gives the correct answer.

This also works:

```
UPDATE workflow_task
SET task_type = 
  CASE
    WHEN workflow_task.id = fr.id THEN 'RRR'
    ELSE 'SSS'
  END
FROM
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY wf.workflow_id
                                  ORDER BY wf.id DESC, wf.workflow_id) AS f_rn,
  wf.id,
  wf.workflow_id
  FROM workflow_task wf
) AS fr
WHERE workflow_task.workflow_id = fr.workflow_id
-- AND fr.f_rn = 1;
```

Note the `ORDER BY wf.id DESC` (the `DESC` part) and I've commented out the `fr.f_rn = 1` predicate.

The [NTH_VALUE()](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-nth_value-function/) function shows how these functions can be used in interesting ways - say you wanted to update the table on the **3rd** record? So this will do it:

```
UPDATE workflow_task
SET task_type = 
  CASE
    WHEN workflow_task.id = fr.f_id THEN 'GGG'
    ELSE 'HHH'
  END
FROM
(
  SELECT NTH_VALUE(wf.id, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY wf.workflow_id 
                                  ORDER BY id, workflow_id) AS f_id,
  wf.workflow_id
  FROM workflow_task wf
) AS fr
WHERE workflow_task.workflow_id = fr.workflow_id;
```

Result:

```
id  task_type   workflow_id
1   HHH 1800
2   HHH 1800
3   GGG 1800  --  <<=== Note - 3rd record modified! 
4   HHH 1800
...
... snipped - 3rd record modified down the line
...
```

Of course, NTH_VALUE(wf.id, 1) reduced to FIRST_VALUE()!

I've also included the [RANK()](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-rank-function/) and [DENSE_RANK()](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-dense_rank-function/) functions in the fiddle - the point is not to get the answer - but so that you can explore these functions which can be used in all sorts of imaginative ways to achieve non-trivial results relatively easily!

### EDIT:

As discussed at the beginning of the answer, my final window function is the LAG() one - this involves the use of `NULL`s. I'll show how this works by starting with the inner `SELECT`:

```
SELECT LAG(wf.workflow_id) OVER (PARTITION BY wf.workflow_id
                              ORDER BY wf.id, wf.workflow_id) AS f_rn,
wf.id,
wf.workflow_id
FROM workflow_task wf
```

Result:

```
f_rn    id  workflow_id
NULL    1   1800
1800    2   1800
1800    3   1800
```

and the final SQL:

```
UPDATE workflow_task
SET task_type = 
  CASE
    WHEN workflow_task.id = fr.id THEN 'LLL'
    ELSE 'MMM'
  END
FROM
(
  SELECT LAG(wf.workflow_id) OVER (PARTITION BY wf.workflow_id
                                  ORDER BY wf.id, wf.workflow_id) AS f_rn,
  wf.id,
  wf.workflow_id
  FROM workflow_task wf
) AS fr
WHERE workflow_task.workflow_id = fr.workflow_id
AND fr.f_rn IS NULL;
```

Result (correct - snipped for brevity):

```
id  task_type   workflow_id
1   LLL 1800
2   MMM 1800
3   MMM 1800
```

If you're inexperienced with these tools, I found it helpful to first consider them using aggregate functions (i.e. AVG(), MIN(), MAX(), SUM(), and COUNT()) as explained well [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/).

A final word of caution - check out the performance analyses at the end of the fiddle - for every up, there's a down (or "Yae cannae beet the law o' physics, Jim - apologies to Gene Rodenberry).

The MIN(id) query appears to be consistently faster than the window function ones. Having said that, it's impossible to tell definitively what will happen with more data - however, I would imagine that, as a general rule, @Akina's query would be faster. I would, however, advise you to test with your own system and data!

p.s. welcome to the forum!

Answer (score 0):

[Akina's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/290546/3684) is flawless for your objective.
Vérace considered all the other options.
For completeness, `EXISTS` is another option:

```
UPDATE workflow_task wt
SET    task_type = 'POC'
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM workflow_task wt1
   WHERE  wt1.workflow_id = wt.workflow_id
   AND    wt1.id < wt.id
   );
   
UPDATE workflow_task wt
SET    task_type = 'Appr'
WHERE  task_type IS NULL;
```

You could do it in a single `UPDATE`. But doing it in two steps has internal benefits. `UPDATE` writes a new row version. Updating all rows in a single command effectively doubles the size of a (pristine) table. If you do it in multiple steps, in separate transactions (and without concurrent load on the DB that would stand in the way), subsequent updates can reuse dead tuples, thereby keep table bloat at bay ..

That said, consider this ...

### Alternative design

Store one pointer to the "poc" row in the parent table, instead of marking all rows in the child table.

```
CREATE TABLE workflow (
  workflow_id int PRIMARY KEY
, work_title text NOT NULL
, poc int --  can be null
);

CREATE TABLE workflow_task (
  workflow_task_id int PRIMARY KEY
, workflow_id int REFERENCES workflow
-- ... more columns
, UNIQUE (workflow_id, workflow_task_id)
);

ALTER TABLE workflow ADD CONSTRAINT workflow_poc_fk FOREIGN KEY (workflow_id, poc) REFERENCES workflow_task (workflow_id, workflow_task_id);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6adc532b13e1ea37b637a89c60c59f19)*

In more detail:

- [Constraint to enforce "at least one" or "exactly one" in a database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112061/constraint-to-enforce-at-least-one-or-exactly-one-in-a-database/112144#112144)