# Insert- and Read-only table in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, permissions, read-only-database

I want to create an "immutable" Postgres database, where users can `insert`/`select` (write/read) data only, but can not `update`/`delete` (change/delete).

I came to know there is `FOR UPDATE` lock, but did not get how to use it.

Let's say for example I've the below table, how can I make it immutable (or, if I understood correctly, how can I use `FOR UPDATE` lock permanently)?

```
CREATE TABLE account(
 user_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
 username VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 password VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
 email VARCHAR (355) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 created_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
 last_login TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: Why don't you just lock the database down using permission sets/roles?

Comment: `SELECT FOR UPDATE` is not permanent (it is tied to the open transaction/session) and it is not intended to block write access for your purpose. You make a table immutable by using database and/or filesystem permissions, instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that "user" does not include any roles with superuser privileges (who can do everything), run this as owner of the table or superuser:

```
REVOKE ALL ON TABLE account FROM public;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON TABLE account TO public;
```

Users also need the `USAGE` privilege for the `SEQUENCE` attached to the `serial` column:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCE account_user_id_seq TO public;
```

About `serial`:

- [Safely rename tables using serial primary key columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14651788/939860)

To make sure of the name of the attached sequence, use `pg_get_serial_sequence()`. See:

- [PostgreSQL SELECT primary key as "serial" or "bigserial"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90555/postgresql-select-primary-key-as-serial-or-bigserial/90567#90567)

You also need the `USAGE` privilege on the schema and `CONNECT` of the database, both of which are granted by default for schema `public`.

If you only want a subset of users to be affected, grant privileges to a group role instead of `public` and grant membership in that role to those users. You still need to revoke privileges from the pseudo-role `public`, which can be viewed as the default group role granting membership to all (irrevocably). And grant whatever is still needed to others (by way of another group role, for instance).

```
CREATE ROLE my_group;
GRANT my_group TO my_user1;
GRANT my_group TO my_user2;  -- more?
REVOKE ... FROM public;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON TABLE account TO my_group;
GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCE account_user_id_seq TO my_group;

CREATE ROLE others;
GRANT others TO other_user1;
GRANT others TO other_user2;
GRANT ... TO others;
```

Related:

- [How to manage DEFAULT PRIVILEGES for USERs on a DATABASE vs SCHEMA?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117109/how-to-manage-default-privileges-for-users-on-a-database-vs-schema/117661#117661)

Comment: It is a good idea to name 'account_user_id_seq'? That name is autogenerated, right? Does Postgres promise to use that (table, column, _seq) naming convention?

Comment: @DavidJ.: No promise, it's just the default. If, on creation, the name is taken, Postgres appends 1, 2, 3 .. until the next free name is found. Use `pg_get_serial_sequence()` to be sure. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/90567/3684

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use table level triggers which prevent `DELETE` and `UPDATE` operations. These kind of triggers usually prevent data updates regardless of user privileges. Also you should use some mechanism to prevent `TRUNCATE`, to make sure, that table cannot be purged, for example `BEFORE TRUNCATE` triggers or some foreign key constraint references.

This will help to create “read-only” table.

Please keep in mind that’s not system level read-only, but if properly implemented, then still brilliant and well working solution.