# In Postgres, what is the relationship between a SEQUENCE and a SERIAL?

Tags: postgresql, sequence

Postgres has the ability to define [SERIAL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) datatypes and [SEQUENCE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createsequence.html) but they seem to overlap in function. What are the main differences ?

Comment: See [dezso's in this q](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47098/how-do-i-determine-if-a-column-is-defined-as-a-serial-data-type-instead-of-an-in)

Comment: The link to the manual that you posted explains that in detail

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`serial` is purely a shorthand way to create an `integer` column with an associated sequence for its default values.

The documentation for `serial` linked from the question even says as much:

> The data types smallserial, serial and bigserial are not true types, but merely a notational convenience for creating unique identifier columns (similar to the AUTO_INCREMENT property supported by some other databases). In the current implementation, specifying:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE tablename (
>     colname SERIAL
> );
> ```
>
> is equivalent to specifying:
>
> ```
> CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq;
> CREATE TABLE tablename (
>     colname integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq')
> );
> ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq OWNED BY tablename.colname;
> ```

Comment: That's very interesting, because there is no mention of a "unique" constraint in there.  That seems to imply that using the "serial" type (notational shorthand, not really type) does *not* guarantee uniqueness—an important point.