# INSERT INTO table FROM SELECT * with nextval() specification

Tags: postgresql, insert, primary-key, sequence

I need to copy records **within** the same table changing only one field.
My table has default-generated sequence `entry_id_seq`, however I am not sure `id` column is SERIAL (how to check that?).

`\d tab` returns just this

```
      Column      |              Type              |            Modifiers            
 -----------------+--------------------------------+------------------------
       id         |             integer            |            not null
...
Indexes:
"tab_entry_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

So the problem is: when I try copy record in a simplified manner:

```
insert into tab_entry select * from tab_entry where id = 3052;
```

it throws error

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tab_entry_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(3052) already exists.
```

Default sequence doesn't generate next value by default. Is there any concise syntax allowing inserting and changing single field without full table specification aka `FROM tab(col1, col2, col3, ..., col N)`?

The table has many fields, so I don't want to write them all, as this will affect code readability.
I want something like this, but this syntax doesn't work

```
insert into tab_entry(id, *) select nextval('seq'), * from tab_entry where id = 3052;
```

And will this `SELECT nextval('seq')` approach work if there be multiple records at once?

Psql and Postgres version is 9.6.2.

Comment: have you designed this table?

Comment: No, it is standard schema of one open-source package Wallabag. Actually it is not intended for manual editing, but currently they haven't developed this functionality at all.

Comment: Multiple rows are no problem, but you cannot avoid listing all the columns (unless you want to use dynamic SQL, I think).  And here is what `serial` is: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/47107/6219

Comment: `insert into tab_entry(id,f1,f2,f3,..) select nextval('seq'),f1,f2,f3,... from tab_entry where id = 3052;`

Comment: @dezso, and if I want to use dynamic SQL? How to achieve that?

Comment: What's wrong with spelling out the  columns? It's good coding style to begin with. Plus: typically SQL clients offer code-completion for table and column names. Using such a feature, writing the insert statement specifying the column names would have taken less time then writing this question.

Comment: psql and code-completion? in a terminal SSH session? seriously?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the comments there is no special syntax for such task.
You could to use combination of functions [`to_json(b)`, `json(b)_set` and `json(b)_populate_record`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html):

```
--drop table if exists t;
create table t(i serial primary key, x int, y text, z timestamp);
insert into t values(default, 1, 'a', now()),(default, 2, 'b', now());

insert into t
select n.*
from t, jsonb_populate_record(
  null::t, 
  jsonb_set(
    to_jsonb(t.*),
    array['i'],
    to_jsonb(nextval('t_i_seq')))) as n;

select * from t;
```

But I think it is not much simpler then just enumerate all columns. You always can use this relatively simple query to get the columns list of table:

```
select string_agg(attname,',' order by attnum)
from pg_attribute
where attrelid = 'public.t'::regclass and attnum > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I use this column query with my initial query? If I use `insert into tab_entry(select string_agg(attname,',' order by attnum)
from pg_attribute
where attrelid = 'public.tab_entry'::regclass and attnum > 0)` it throws syntax error.

Comment: @Suncatcher You can not. It is for "Copy-paste" technology :o)